# Angular 7 disable scroll to top on Sub Route Change

Tags: angular, angular7, angular7-router

I have 2 options for scrolling to the top of the page.
First,

```
router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
    if (evt instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        window.scroll({
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            behavior: 'smooth'
        });
    }
});
```

and the second option is available from Angular 6 is,

```
RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes, { 
      scrollPositionRestoration: "enabled"
})
```

When I change my route, Page is moving to top which is working as expected.
I have tab section at almost bottom of the page using sub route. When the sub route is triggered, the page is moving to the top of the page instead of remaining in the tab section.

So I need to disable the scroll to top functionality on the sub route. Is there any way to do it?

Any help/idea is appreciated.

Comment: Did you found an elegant solution to this because i am facing the same issue?

Comment: any solution to this?

Comment: In some project, the scroll is given to a div and not to the main body. So, if u write a scroll to the body, it won`t work. Write to that particular div. Is that a help ?

Answer (score 6):

It might work if you check the current route is one of those sub routes of your tab section before you scroll to top.

```
//for scalability, define routes you don't want to scroll to top in a string array

const noScrollRoutes: string[] = ['route/tabSubRoute1', 'route/tabSubRoute2'];

router.events.subscribe((evt) => {
    if (evt instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        if(noScrollRoutes.find(this.router.url) == undefined){ //if can't a route in predefined array, scroll to top
           window.scroll({
               top: 0,
               left: 0,
               behavior: 'smooth'
           });
        }
    }
});
```

Also, you probably need to remove `scrollPositionRestoration: "enabled"`, keep it disabled.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. It will work for sure, but I have a very big and evolving project where I cannot update every time. if there is any way where I can check sub-routes dynamically. It will be an accurate and one-time activity.

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you want to be able to check that tab section's sub routes only? Maybe you can try `this.router.url.indexOf("tabSectionRoute")` or you can try using regexp.prototype.search(). E.g. `\yourRegExp\.test(this.router.url)`, with yourRegExp to be your regular expression to test if this.router.url contains part of your tab section route.